# Set theory resource for an educated non-mathematician

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

A friend of mine has asked for a reference to a resource for self study of set theory (for the sake of it). He has knowledge of basic predicate logic.

The books I know of are not suited for a non-mathematician, because even if they assume no prior knowledge, they are written in very technical fashion.
Video series I know of (i.e. youtube videos) tend to be too superficial.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: As (rightly) suggested in the comments, I'll expand a bit: I think a good book or lecture would be one that includes an introduction to the basic naive stuff (cardinals, ordinals, AC and it's equivalences). As well as nice "showcase" of results from these ideas (i.e. $|\mathbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0=|\mathbb{N}|$).

Comment: Not to tout my own horn, [but... this might be useful.](https://ests.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/note1.pdf)

Comment: it comes to my mind *Naive set theory* of Halmos.

Comment: Perhaps this one (at least it's free): http://www.math.ku.edu/~roitman/SetTheory.pdf If that's too technical, then perhaps start with a chapter on set theory from a standard Discrete Math text.

Comment: @Masacroso: What a terrible book. :(

Comment: @j3M: It could be more beneficial if you tell us ***what*** you're looking to achieve. Is it more about naive stuff? Up to the notion of ordinals and perhaps some basic transfinite recursion and induction? The proof that the axiom of choice is consistent with the rest of ZF? The independence of CH? Fine structure and consistency of combinatorial principles in L? If you give a specific target, it will be easier to give a more correct recommendation.

Comment: For naive set theory, this one might fit: Kaplansky -- Set Theory and Metric Spaces (1972). It's two separate books, packaged as one. The first book is the one on Set Theory.

Comment: @j3M: Kaplansky's book covers cardinals, ordinals, the axiom of choice, all at the naive level, but still rigorous. And in my opinion, _all_ of Kaplansky's books are very well written.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Thanks for the suggestions on editing the question. Also, thanks for your note (the one you posted), I'll take time to look into it! Out of curiosity, why is Halmos' book terrible in your opinion?

Comment: @quasi: FYI, Kaplansky's book is where I first learned a little about ordinal and cardinal numbers (meaning, besides basic countability and uncountability and cardinal equality examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend might be interested in

Sets, logic, and axiomatic theories / by Robert R. Stoll | 1961

The first chapter should be accessible to your friend:

[image]

The book can be checked out online from the [Internet Archive](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL5820686M/Sets_logic_and_axiomatic_theories.).

It should be pointed out that the world wide web is an incredible resource. Using search engines your friend could find relevant links by looking for keywords found in Stoll's Chapter 1. For example, use duckduckgo.com on

[sets ordering relations math](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sets%20ordering%20relations%20math&atb=v91-7_f&ia=web)

If your friend is interested "in cardinals, ordinals, AC and it's equivalences... and 'showcase' of results from these ideas (i.e.  $|\mathbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0=|\mathbb{N}|$)", you should point them towards this site!

Interested in learning about cardinals? Could not find a duckduckgo bang, but this works,

[cardinals site:www.math.stackexchange.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cardinals%20site%3Awww.math.stackexchange.com&atb=v91-7_f&ia=web)