# Reference Request: Set Theory graduate introduction

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, book-recommendation

I'm essentially looking for a book on set theory that would include material that begins to go deeper for a student who has/currently taken algebra, topology, and analysis undergrad courses.

Edit: I found Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory through GTM, which hopefully seems to be what I'm looking for. Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: See [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670853/set-theory-resource-for-an-educated-non-mathematician#comment5516777_2670853) here...

Comment: I'll let one of MSE's hardcore set theorists post an actual answer, but two that come to my mind are *Set Theory* by Thomas Jech and *Set Theory: An Introduction to Induction Proofs* by Kenneth Kunen.

Comment: Very much appreciated! I'll look into these.

Comment: The subtitle to Kunen's book is "an introduction to *independence* proofs"

Comment: I think Kunen's book is a little difficult if you have zero experience with set theory, and your mathematical background is "algebra, topology, and analysis undergrad courses." As is Jech's book. I would go with Introduction to set theory by Jech and Hrbacek. @CliveNewstead BTW the new edition of Kunen's book no longer has the subtitle, the subtitled book is very very old. Anyway, I don't think I'd start with Kunen, even though it is my favorite mathematics textbook.