# Looking for a good book to read about limit ordinals, aleph and beth numbers and AC

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I have read it the Appendix of Kelley's book *General Topology* for a self-teaching introduction to Set Theory. That means: I know the general definition of ordinals, and thus the definition of naturals and cardinals. I can know that not ordinal has a predecesor, and that successor ordinals and cardinals may be different. Hence I manage with the definitions of partial, orders, total orders, linear orders... And theoretically with maps between ordered structures. I mean, I think I have undertood (mor or less) the Appendix of Kelley's books (only I have read until theorem 174, if $x$ is an infinite cardinal then $\mbox{card }x+1 = \mbox{card} x$) . And that is all my basis.

So I would like to continue studying it, focus on limit ordinals and cardinals (for example in the well-known definiton $\lambda = \bigcup_{\kappa\in\lambda}\kappa$), cofinality, aleph and beth numbers, the importance of the Axiom of Choice in their definitions, the Continuum Hypothesis and the generalized CH, etc. And I would like to understand the difference between induction, strong induction and transfinite induction principles, because for example, the only difference I can see between strong induction and transfinite induction explained by Enderton is that the first consider only $\omega$ when the second is in every well-ordered set. But the proof is the same. And for me there is no difference between induction and stron induction.

I think Enderton's book discuss alll of these topics, but I his approach is different from Kelley's ones and I don't feel much comfortable. I'll read it if you think is the best book but I don't like it much.

For me Bourbaki is always an option, but I've read his Theory of sets is not very good. They develop their own theory, quite strange and very out of phase nowadays.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen that note I wrote with this information and I keep linking to it in comments to questions like this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: no. I don't. I don't know what are you talking about, sorry

Comment: [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672388/reference-request-set-theory-graduate-introduction#comment5519682_2672388), for example.

Comment: Let me also point out that you're essentially looking for a book about set theory. But you're not telling us what do you already know, and what is your endgame goal. This would make the main difference between recommending something more heavy weight or something more lightweight.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question.

Comment: [Here is a list of books](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=224913) that I posted in sci.math on 5 February 2000, but I'm sure there are probably more extensive lists posted in Stack Exchange by now. I thought I had posted such a list in Stack Exchange, but I can't find it now. I could easily now add quite a few books to those I gave in my 2000 list if I wanted to, but unfortunately this is not something I'm presently interested doing. Besides, you should be able to find 30+ such books pretty quickly by googling.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks a lot.

Comment: URL gives 404.Please fix.

Comment: @Plotinus: I didn't see your comment until now (over 2.5 years later) because you didn't [notify me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020), and I don't go looking back at my (probably thousands of) comments that are 3+ years old (URL given about 3 years before your comment) to see if anyone replied. The only reason I saw your comment now is that this question was bumped up to the "first page queue" by a Community Bot action of some sort. That said, [this is the google-groups link to that 5 February 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/fl10B4wEvxY/m/qkkVIBDmhIkJ).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two references:

Kenneth Kunen: [Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848900503) (Studies in Logic: Mathematical Logic and Foundations, new edition), 2011.

Thomas Jech: [Set Theory](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9783540440857) (3rd Edition), 2006.

Both of them have some exercises in order to get some more deep insight about the theory.

Comment: By Thomas Jech I suppose you mean Karel Hrbacek Thomas Jech,   Introduction to Set Theory, Third Edition, Revised, and Expanded (Pure and Applied Mathematics (Marcel Dekker)), don't you? Maybe I should add this comment, I have been looking at it and I don't like so much. I prefer Enderton. Respect to Kenneth, I didn't know him. I'll try to get the book.

Comment: @Dog_69 Pretty sure he means [Jech: Set Theory](https://www.amazon.de/Set-Theory-Millennium-Monographs-Mathematics/dp/3642078990/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1520594339&sr=8-2&keywords=jech+set+theory). It's invaluable but quite densely written. Kunen's book has a much easier pace -- maybe better suited to self-study.

Comment: Ok. What happens is that the book written together with Hrbacek is also the third edition ''Revised and expanded''. Thanks @StefanMesken. By the way, I had forgotten include cofinality as required topic. Jech's book talks about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Dog_69 - I added links in order to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: How about Keith Devlin’s Joy of Sets.